# Facing issue in installing spree_auth_devise in rails '4.2.4'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree-auth-devise

As I am new in spree in my gem file I have included

```
gem 'spree'
gem 'spree_auth_devise'
```

and run bundle install
I get error:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       spree_auth_devise (>= 0) ruby depends on
>         devise (~> 2.0.4) ruby depends on
>           railties (~> 3.1) ruby
>
> ```
> sass-rails (~> 5.0) ruby depends on
>   railties (4.2.4)
> ```

Please help me out how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this, in your gem file:

```
gem 'spree', '3.0.1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```